# Basic question on tossing coins

Tags: probability

Generally the sample space of two events

1. Tossing three coins at a time
2. Tossing one coin three times

are considered same . But I really don't know how can these two events be the same even in mathematics ?

I know this is a very silly question but I genuinely want to know about this .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you but you just need to consider all possible cases for three coins at a time if one side is named head and other one tails: {(h,h,h),(h,h,t),(h,t,t),(t,t,t),(t,h,h),(t,t,h),(h,t,h),(t,h,t)} and since tossing three coins separately dose not make any difference in the chance of head or tails would be the same so they have same sample space.

Comment: Can you explain why you think they should be different? We're assuming the coins are ideal: tossing a coin doesn't damage it or alter it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the probability of heads or tails for the result of tossing any coin is 0.5. The events are independent.  There is no difference to the probability of obtaining 0, 1, 2 or 3 heads if three coins are tossed simultaneously or one coin three times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming independence,

The sample space of the experiment 1. is the following

$$\{(TTT),(CTT),(TCT),(TTC),(TCC),(CTC),(CCT),(CCC)\}$$

Here the outcomes $(ABC)$ indicate the outcomes of the three coins.

The sample space of the experiment 2. is the following

$$\{(TTT),(CTT),(TCT),(TTC),(TCC),(CTC),(CCT),(CCC)\}$$

Here the outcomes $(ABC)$ indicate the outcomes of the three tosses of the single coin.

Mathematically, if you want to calculate some probabilities in the two experiments, the results is evidently the same

---

Intuitive explanation.

Consider the Experiment 2 but tossing the coin repeatedly at the light speed...it is self evident that this overlaps with Experiment 1